# How to get older CE 6.0 updates

Tags: windows-ce, updates

I'm working on a project with CE 6.0 and I need to rebuild the tree. My problem is that I have to update the tree up to May 2009, this requires the 2008 rollup and the following 5 monthly updates, but I can't find them (there's the 2009 rollup and the following 2010 monthly updates).

I can't upgrade to a newer release as our platform is incompatible with R3 and post-May 2009 updates.

Of course if it would be possible to upgrade the platform so that it would be compatible with R3, I would upgrade, but it is currently not possible for two reasons:

1. There's a third party middleware that's not compatible with R3.
2. The product that has already been deployed (hundreds of thousands of devices) has currently an image based on CE 6.0 R2 upgraded to May 2009, an I want to recreate that environment.

Is there a place where I can download the "archived" updates?

Comment: I currently do not have any active MSDN subscription account, but I do remember that even until 2 years ago there were still downloads for even 16-bit OS versions. If you have access to an MSDN subscription you might want to check there for older version of Windows CE and most other Microsoft software versions of that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Mobile & Embedded Communications Extranet (ECE](https://ece.partners.extranet.microsoft.com/ece)) is where the embedded channel resources are archived, but it is an authenticated access site.  Credentials are usually obtained through the distributor that the embedded product development tools and licenses are obtained from (distributors like Arrow).

The embedded team [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/) could be a place to begin looking for contact information for folk within Microsoft.

Once you get access, [Embedded > Products > Download Center > Windows Embedded > Windows CE](https://ece.partners.extranet.microsoft.com/ece/Embedded/Products/ProductSupplements/Embedded/CE/default.htm) contains:

> Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R2 Release - Product Download
>   Applicable to: Embedded Distributors and OEMs Who Purchase Through Distribution
>
> The Microsoft® Update Windows® Embedded CE 6.0 R2 software is now available for download on the ECE. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R2 provides the latest breakthrough technologies that enable Windows® Embedded CE 6.0 device makers to quickly and easily build small footprint devices that connect to Windows Vista® and Windows® Server 2008.
>   ...
>   Posted: November 13, 2007

[Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Updates](https://ece.partners.extranet.microsoft.com/ece/Embedded/Products/ProductSupplements/Embedded/CE/DistOEM-UpdatesforOEMs-CE6.0.htm) contains:

> Product Updates for Microsoft® Windows® Embedded CE 6.0. 
>   For individual updates prior to January 2009 please contact your MS Authorized Distributor.